# Why does JAXBContext need to be told specifically about a class that is already in the package?

Tags: jaxb

This program:

```
import foo.bar.baz.ClassSpecificallyIncluded;  
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;  
public class A {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassSpecificallyIncluded.class).toString());  
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance("foo.bar.baz").toString());  
    }  
}
```

produces different output for the first and second JAXBContext:

> jar:file:/C:/dev/trunk/rt/tomcat/shared/lib/webservices-rt-2.0.1.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.class Build-Id: 1.0
>   Classes known to this context:
>    [B
>    boolean
>    byte
>    char
>    foo.bar.baz.Class1
>    foo.bar.baz.Class1$NestedClass
>    foo.bar.baz.Class2
>    foo.bar.baz.ClassSpecificallyIncluded
>    foo.bar.baz.AnotherClass
>    com.sun.xml.bind.api.CompositeStructure
>    double
>    float
>    int
>    java.awt.Image
>    java.io.File
>    java.lang.Boolean
>    java.lang.Byte
>    java.lang.Character
>    java.lang.Class
>    java.lang.Double
>    java.lang.Float
>    java.lang.Integer
>    java.lang.Long
>    java.lang.Object
>    java.lang.Short
>    java.lang.String
>    java.lang.Void
>    java.math.BigDecimal
>    java.math.BigInteger
>    java.net.URI
>    java.net.URL
>    java.util.Calendar
>    java.util.Date
>    java.util.GregorianCalendar
>    java.util.UUID
>    javax.activation.DataHandler
>    javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
>    javax.xml.datatype.Duration
>    javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
>    javax.xml.namespace.QName
>    javax.xml.transform.Source
>    long
>    short
>    void
>
> jar:file:/C:/dev/trunk/rt/tomcat/shared/lib/webservices-rt-2.0.1.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.class Build-Id: 1.0
>   Classes known to this context:
>    [B
>    boolean
>    byte
>    char
>    foo.bar.baz.Class1
>    foo.bar.baz.Class1$NestedClass
>    foo.bar.baz.Class2
>    **<<< CLASS IS MISSING HERE>>>**
>    foo.bar.baz.AnotherClass
>    com.sun.xml.bind.api.CompositeStructure
>    double
>    float
>    int
>    java.awt.Image
>    java.io.File
>    java.lang.Boolean
>    java.lang.Byte
>    java.lang.Character
>    java.lang.Class
>    java.lang.Double
>    java.lang.Float
>    java.lang.Integer
>    java.lang.Long
>    java.lang.Object
>    java.lang.Short
>    java.lang.String
>    java.lang.Void
>    java.math.BigDecimal
>    java.math.BigInteger
>    java.net.URI
>    java.net.URL
>    java.util.Calendar
>    java.util.Date
>    java.util.GregorianCalendar
>    java.util.UUID
>    javax.activation.DataHandler
>    javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
>    javax.xml.datatype.Duration
>    javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
>    javax.xml.namespace.QName
>    javax.xml.transform.Source
>    long
>    short
>    void

And yet, ClassSpecificallyIncluded is in the foo.bar.baz package:

```
//  
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6   
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a>   
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema.   
// Generated on: 2012.05.14 at 10:47:17 PM IST   
//  

package foo.bar.baz;  

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;  


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {  
    "applicationArea",  
    "dataArea"  
})  
@XmlRootElement(name = "ClassSpecificallyIncluded")  
public class ClassSpecificallyIncluded {...
```

The classpath and classloader are the same for both JAXBContexts.

So why doesn’t the second JAXBContext know about ClassSpecificallyIncluded?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is effectively answered here:

[Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

**Answer:**
No By design, java doesn't know and can't find every class in a package.  Java is built on the concept of "Just in time".  Which for this purpose means that java doesn't know what it's got until it's asked for something specifically.

So from that stand point, JAXB has no way to find what classes are in a package.

It would be inconvenient if JAXB had to be told precisely every class every time you needed context.  So as a convenience method JAXB offers you the option of providing a package name.

In order to get round the limitations of java it attempts to load from that package an `ObjectFactory` and a `jaxb.index` file.  It can do this because they are specific names.  If one is found, then it uses them as a manifest for the package.  If neither is found it has no option but to abort because it can't possibly know what's in the package.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

### Creating a JAXBContext on a Package Name

Assume I have the following classes in a directory called `forum20273355`:

- Address
- Customer (extends Person)
- Mammal
- Person (extends Mammal & has property of type Address)

If I create a `JAXBContext` using the following code:

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("forum20273355");
```

Then I will get the following exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "forum20273355" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "forum20273355" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:334)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:431)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:394)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:298)
    at forum20273355.Demo.main(Demo.java:8)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "forum20273355" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:172)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:132)
    ... 5 more
```

### Specifying a `jaxb.index` or `ObjectFactory`

Below we will create a `jaxb.index` file and `ObjectFactory` that will cause the `Person` class to be processed to see what happens.

**jaxb.index**

`jaxb.index` is a text file that contains a carriage return separated list of short class names.

```
Person
```

**ObjectFactory**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public Person createPerson() {
        return new Person();
    }

}
```

**Processed Classes**

Obviously `Person` was processed, but so was the super class `Mammal` and the reference class `Address`.  The class that wasn't processed was the subclass `Customer`.

```
forum20273355.Address
forum20273355.Mammal
forum20273355.Person
```

### Getting the Subclass Processed

Obviously we could have added the subclass `Customer` to the `jaxb.index` or `ObjectFactory`.  We can also leverage the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation to make this happen.

```java
package forum20273355;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso({Customer.class})
public class Person extends Mammal {
```

Now `Customer` is processed as well.

```
forum20273355.Address
forum20273355.Customer
forum20273355.Mammal
forum20273355.Person
```

---

### UPDATE

Everything you wrote in your comment is true.  What is missing is that the `jaxb.index` file or `ObjectFactory` class is required to kick of the process.  When a model is generated from an XML schema an `ObjectFactory` is generated containing all the necessary references to bootstrap the model.  When you start from Java classes I recommend bootstrapping from Java classes instead of the package name, but the same rules apply.

> But the Sun Oracle documentation says: JAXBContext.newInstance(
>   "com.acme.foo:com.acme.bar" ) The JAXBContext instance is initialized
>   from a list of colon separated Java package names.

True, the package names specify where metadata will be looked for.

> Each java package contains JAXB mapped classes, schema-derived classes
>   and/or user annotated classes.

True.

> Additionally, the java package may contain JAXB package annotations
>   that must be processed. (see JLS 3rd Edition, Section 7.4.1. Package
>   Annotations).

True, the package annotations will definitely be applied.

Comment: But the Sun Oracle documentation says: JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo:com.acme.bar" ) 
The JAXBContext instance is initialized from a list of colon separated Java package names. Each java package contains JAXB mapped classes, schema-derived classes and/or user annotated classes. Additionally, the java package may contain JAXB package annotations that must be processed. (see JLS 3rd Edition, Section 7.4.1. Package Annotations). Where does it say anything about subclasses, etc.?

Comment: @user1461450 - Your comment is true, and doesn't conflict with my answer. I have added an update to provide more information.

Comment: Hm. The ObjectFactory in this package does not have a QName for ClassSpecificallyIncluded. (It's not my package, just trying to use it.) Hadn't noticed that before. But ClassSpecificallyIncluded is not a subclass or superclass. It's by itself. So it would be unnatural to be required to add XmlSeeAlso. Anyway, it appears that the package was not generated correctly, and thus the problem. Thanks for your answer!