# JAXB marshalling in Apache Camel

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel, marshalling

I am new to Apache camel and need to perform a task where I need to marshal an object to XML file. I am using the below code but it is not working. Here, `foo.pojo` is package where JAXB annotated classes are present

```
JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat =  new JaxbDataFormat("foo.pojo");
from("direct:start").marshal(jaxbDataFormat).to("file:C:/Users/Anand.Jain/Desktop/hello/abc.xml").end();
```

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1: Configure the context path**

```
JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat =  new JaxbDataFormat("foo.pojo");
```

`OptionFactory` or `jaxb.index` file must be defined in the given package as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273355/why-does-jaxbcontext-need-to-be-told-specifically-about-a-class-that-is-already).

**Option 2: Configure the class(es) to be bound**

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyAnnotatedClass.class);
JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat(jaxbContext);
```

I prefere Option 2.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Option 1 is recently impossible as *JaxbDataFormat(String)* constructor is not available [as you can see in official javadoc](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/model/dataformat/JaxbDataFormat.html)</strike>

Documentation seems to be outdated about this point.

**EDIT: BE CAREFUL there's TWO JaxbDataFormat**

I have understood: there's TWO jaxbDataFormat in camel ecosystem

- one is in *camel-core* package *org.apache.camel.model.dataformat*
- another in *camel-jaxb* package *org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb*

Comment: And option 2 too :/ because of refactoring of JaxbDataFormat.

package org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat seems to be moved to org.apache.camel.model.dataformat in camel-core 2.14..1