# Can't add application.prop to Camel test

Tags: java, spring, properties, apache-camel

I can't make my test use application.propperies in test envirement while on main it works fine. Write that it cant find such a propperty. I tried to use @TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties") but didn't help. Also added application.propperies to resource in test folder.

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL237.png)

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
//@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
public class Excercise5to7ApplicationTests extends CamelTestSupport {


    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new MyRoute();
    }

    @Before
    public void mockEndpoints() throws Exception {
        AdviceWithRouteBuilder mockKafka = new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // mock the for testing
                interceptSendToEndpoint("kafka:*")
                        .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                        .to("mock:kafka");
            }
        };
        RouteDefinition myRoute = context.getRouteDefinition("myRoute");
        myRoute.adviceWith(context, mockKafka);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithRealFile() throws Exception {
        context.start();
        MockEndpoint kafka = getMockEndpoint("mock:kafka");
        kafka.expectedMessageCount(10);
        kafka.assertIsSatisfied();
        context.stop();
    }
    @Override
    protected Context createJndiContext() throws Exception {
        JndiContext context = new JndiContext();
        context.bind("myBean", new MyBean());
        return context;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The exception itself:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property with key [route.from.path] not found in properties from text: file:{{route.from.path}}?noop=true

    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1774)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.initRouteInputs(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:380)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.prepareRouteImp(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:298)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.prepareRoute(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:270)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.route(RoutesDefinition.java:205)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.from(RoutesDefinition.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.from(RouteBuilder.java:169)
    at com.bisnode.excercise5to7.Routes.MyRoute.configure(MyRoute.java:16)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.checkInitialized(RouteBuilder.java:462)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.configureRoutes(RouteBuilder.java:402)
    at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.addRoutesToCamelContext(RouteBuilder.java:383)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$1.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:971)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$1.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:968)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3108)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:968)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.doSetUp(CamelTestSupport.java:352)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.setUp(CamelTestSupport.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property with key [route.from.path] not found in properties from text: file:{{route.from.path}}?noop=true
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.getPropertyValue(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:271)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.readProperty(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.doParse(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.parse(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:100)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser.parseUri(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:230)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:173)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(DefaultCamelContext.java:2411)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinitionHelper.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(ProcessorDefinitionHelper.java:735)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.initRouteInputs(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:378)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Where are you loading the spring context file? Are you using annotation based config or xml based config?

Comment: @notionquest im using spring boot and do not touch any config

Comment: Can you show the CamelTestSupport class?

Comment: This seems to be more of the limitation in Camel. You may need to configure it based on the camel version that you are using. Please refer this link http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: @notionquest well CamelTestSupport class is 1k line long.Here is link https://ideone.com/e.js/DIzzz8  Read page about props and couldnt find any sing of props being used at test at any specific way

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue loading a properties file in a Test and I overrode the protected method "useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent" available through CamelTestSupport class. For example:

```
@Override
protected Properties useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent()
{
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  try
  {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(
      "./src/test/resources/test.properties"));
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    fail(e.getMessage());
  }

return properties;
```

}

You can find more information here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Answer (score 0):

A shorter variant of  @CookieSoup answer could be to update the `Camel Context` for `properties` component.

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class YourRouterTest extends CamelTestSupport
{
    ...

    @Override
    protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception
    {
        SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
        registry.put("beanName", bean);

        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
        camelContext.addRoutes(yourRoutes);

        PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
        pc.setLocation("classpath:application.properties");
        camelContext.addComponent("properties", pc);

        return camelContext;
    }

    ...
}
```