# JAXBException : no package name is given

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

for XML File parsing I am using JAXB but after compilation following error is reported

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: No package name is given
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at searchAlgo.Question.<init>(Question.java:16)
```

code is given below

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Question {
//String question = new String() ;
String s = new String();
Question()
{
    try{
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\levels.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(s); 

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        String string = (String) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        System.out.println(string);


    }
    catch(JAXBException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

do I need to install JAXB plug-in?
i am using jdk 1.8.0_91 and eclipse mars

Comment: This question has been asked before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273355/why-does-jaxbcontext-need-to-be-told-specifically-about-a-class-that-is-already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is that you're not using JAXB correctly.**

First,

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(s);
```

is wrong because `JAXBContext.newInstance(...)` is expecting either a class or *" separated java package names that contain schema-derived classes and/or fully qualified JAXB-annotated classes"* according to **[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html)**

The point is to determine what kind of objects JAXB is dealing with. In other words, it will be what kind of objects you have inside `C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\levels.xml` XML file.

Second,

if you want to unmarshall objects from XML file or marshall objects to String, I suggest you read the following documentation with a lot of examples:

- [**Marshaller**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html)
- [**Unmarshaller**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html)

Answer (score 1):

JAXBContext.newInstance() expects either a Class or a package name. Since s is a String, it is interpreted as a package name. But your String is empty, so you get "No package name is given"